# SQLalchemy cannot find my table

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to follow the [official SQLalchemy tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html), but less than half way through it blows up in my face. I am using the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
session = Session()

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Sequence
class Substance(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'substances'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence("substance_id_seq"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    hazards = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Substance(name='%s', fullname='%s', hazards='%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.hazards)

edta = Substance(name="EDTA", fullname="Ethylenediaminetetraacetic acid", hazards="lala")
session.add(edta)

subs = session.query(Substance).filter_by(name='EDTA').first()
print subs
```

This fails with:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: substances [SQL: u'SELECT substances.id AS substances_id, substances.name AS substances_name, substances.fullname AS substances_fullname, substances.hazards AS substances_hazards \nFROM substances \nWHERE substances.name = ?\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'] [parameters: ('EDTA', 1, 0)]`

Any ideas why or what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` to your code after all the classes are declared.
This creates all the tables you have declared through objects.

Also, another thing, use `session.commit()` to commit all the data you added through `session.add(obj)`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. But for some reason the guide seems to imply that I should get some output without having to run those two lines. They are mentioned in the guide, but only after the query line. Any ideas why?

Comment: The explanation on `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` is given in the guide. Read carefully, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#create-a-schema